# ArcGIS: How to identify corner buildings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

In ArcGIS I have a polygone with buildings (from osm) and I have to select all the corner buildings. since I am new with GIS I don't know how to solve that. Tried to buffer all the intersect points of the streets, assuming that the the buildings within the buffer are all corner points, but to many non-corner-buildings are selected with that methode. Has anyone an idea how I can solve that?

[image]

Comment: Building off your existing trial, my first thought is to buffer each point based on its distance + 1 from the nearest polygon, which would produce asymmetrical buffers and fewer overlapping polygons.  But the points on the south side of the road are going to overlap non-corner-buildings also.  You probably need to simplify the road network so you can work with a single intersection point.

Comment: Create small negative buffer inside building s. Convert to polylines and split at vertices. Spatial join to streets, closest, one to one. Sort by street name. Summarise by building id, statistics first and last street name. Buildings with different first/last are your candidates

Comment: @FelixIP Sounds good, but the convert to polylines and split lines tools are only available at Advanced Version of ArcMap and I only have Standart Version  :( At the moment I try to find a workaround to split the lines into segments, but without any look so far.

Comment: Create empty polygon feature class. Start editing, select all polylines, use advanced editing toolbox icon to construct polygons

Comment: Hi Felix, thank's for your your fast answer. I am not sure if I unterstood you right, how will I get the line segments that I need for your workflow to do the spatial join? Your answer confuses me... :)

Comment: @Beaugart post a screenshot of the result please... sounds interesting!